# Expansion while processing math in lists with xparse

Tags: expl3, expansion, xparse, comma-separated-list, token-lists

I'm trying to "print" a comma-separated list of strings. The actual use case is more complex, the list being stored as a key-value, but the MWE below shows the problem: *when I add math to the list, the compiler complains with "command undefined".* (Stuff like `\linetwo` below works fine, though.)

Sometimes `\noexpand` helped (e.g. `$\noexpand\bm{v}$` would work, but `$\bm{v}` wouldn't). This made me think maybe messing with expansion would help, and I went through the options for `\mycmd`, settling on `\exp_args:Nx`, though this may well be the wrong choice. Help from someone perhaps more experienced with expl3 would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\processline}{m}{#1\par}
\NewDocumentCommand{\processlist}{ >{\SplitList{,}} m }{\ProcessList{#1}{\processline}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{m}{\exp_args:Nx \processlist{#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\linetwo}{}{line 2}

\begin{document}

\mycmd{line 1, \linetwo, $\text{v}_\text{v}$}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know expl3; however, I'm sure that you don't want to expand the lists before processing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

expl3 has a clist module for mapping over comma lists:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{m}{\clist_map_inline:nn{#1}{##1\par}}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\linetwo}{}{line 2}

\begin{document}

\mycmd{line 1, \linetwo, $\text{v}_{\text{v}}$}
    
\end{document}
```